# VBA missing Worksheet.Range as a value and continuously get Object variable not set (Error 91)

Tags: excel, vba, visio

```
Public Sub InputData(var)
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\Jordan.Jennings\Desktop\Programs{}\Test.xlsx"
WB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
ibox = 1
E = 8.5
N = 10
W = 7.5
S = 9.75
Do Until ibox = var
    Set I = ActivePage.DrawRectangle(E, N, W, S)
    I.Text = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    N = N - 0.25
    S = S - 0.25
    ibox = ibox + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Ok I have tried so many things - What i am trying to do is draw a bunch of boxes in visio with text in them from an excel document and when i do worksheets("Sheet1").Range the .Range does not come up as an option and i throw the error 91 Please help I am at a loss here

Comment: Silly question, but the workbook actually has a sheet named `Sheet1`? What if you tried `WB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value`?  Is that workbook path correct?  Also you need to do `Set WB = ...` I believe, since  you declared `WB` as a workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WB` is a `Workbook` object reference.

```
WB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
```

You can't assign an object reference like this.

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
```

That should fix it.

Comment: What he said. (I didn't see that he didn't put a `set`)

Comment: Yes that was it! Ha so frustrating little misses like that. Thank you so much!